# I try save bitmap image in my SDcard using android studio

Tags: android, image, save

Please help me to solve this problem in my code ,I would like to save the bitmap image (newimage) into SD card in my phone (Galaxy j7), but I get the error (no such file or directory)

```
File filepath;
    filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

   File  dir = new File(filepath.getAbsolutePath()+"/save image");
    dir.mkdirs();
    File  file = new File(dir,"myimage.png");
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"image saved to SD",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   try{

        OutputStream stream ;

        stream = new FileOutputStream(file);

        newimage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100,stream);

        stream.flush();

        stream.close();

    }catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Parse the saved image path to uri
    Uri savedImageURI = Uri.parse(filepath.getAbsolutePath());

    // Display the saved image to ImageView
  //  imagev.setImageURI(savedImageURI);

    // Display saved image uri to TextView
    tv_saved.setText("Image saved in external storage.\n" + savedImageURI);
```

the error message is :

```
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/save image/myimage.png (No such file or directory)
```

I added the permission of write in manifest.xml as follow:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="21" />
<uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21"/>
```

Comment: Directory names shouldn't have space, try changing the save directory to `/saveimage`

Comment: I tried this ,but now change

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no problem with your codes, the problem is the version of Android that you are compiling your project on. On higher versions of the Android you should implement runtime permission for storage permission.

Refer to the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33162451/4359933) which is going to solve your problem.

**Edit:** There is another problem with your implementation  that I recognized after posting my answer. Before trying to save your image on the directory named **save image** you should create this folder by implementing

`String folder_main = "save image";
File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), folder_main);
if(!f.exists()) {f.mkdirs();}`

Comment: my version of android studio is 3.2.1 ,what the version must be installed?

Comment: but it written in the code as :File  dir = new File(filepath.getAbsolutePath()+"/save image");
        dir.mkdirs();

Comment: the problem is not excatly the version of the android. The line of code that you have posted not generates the directory named save image. You should either generate the directory by code that I have posted above or manually using file explorer on your device.

Comment: thank you for this note about generate folder manually ,now i tried that on my device but i can't , i have the just the path: storage/emulated   in my sd card , and when i tried to create directory with name 0 it refused and view error message "sorry ,failed"

Comment: 0 is default number of storage device. Leave it only create save image  directory

Comment: I have file explorer ES app. in my device , when I view the SD card content it view storage/emulated , and I can't add any folder ,using this app , what do you think?

Comment: I am also using Es file explorer. Choose internal storage an there is settings menu on top right corner(three dots) click it which opens dialog. On dialog there is new option and click it to create new folder

Comment: I feel heavy for you, but bear for the last time please...I create folder with name **new image** but the new error message changed to (permission denied)..can you help me by update my code because I'm in the first steps in the android.thank you for help

Comment: could you please share the error message? Have you get error on android studio?

Comment: thank you very much ,my problem solved , it was in my phone setting

Comment: the answer which solved the problem was in my device(mobile phone)... go to **settings-->Apps-->choose your android app-->permissions-->Storage**  activate **storage**